# Configurable Data-Visualization based on Json-Schema

Tags: data-visualization, graphs, data-analysis, json, schema

I'm looking for a configurable data visualization tool using a json File as data-source.
The json schema is not defined yet. But let's say the file will contain data like:

- time-series data (for example array of json objects)
- histogram data (for example of temperatur objects)
- tabular data (for example objects containing strings)

Now, I'm looking for a tool where i can configure a nice view for this data, based on the (pre-known) json schema.

For example:

- Show a array of Temperatur-Objects as a linechart
- Show histogram data in a histogram plot
- Show tabular data in a table with column for example "Name, Adress"

In my usecase, typically a json - datafile is a complete/closed set of data.

Optional:

- It would be nice to have a option to compare diffeerent data-sets - but that's optional.
- It would be nice to have the option to do some basic data analysis on the input data (For example variance of Temperatur-Objects Time-Series)

What I found so far:
Most tools I found, are full blown data analytic tools. They use a database as backend and supports different data import features.

- tableau
- Grafana  (Focused mostly on time-series data. )
- Superset
- Snowplow

As I said, my json datafile is a enclosed/complete dataset. Therefore I'm not sure if I'm on the right track with these database backend analaytic tools.

Thanks.